# How to understand the return values of scipy.interpolate.splrep

Tags: scipy, interpolation

### Background

Continuation of [Spline interpolation - why cube with 2nd derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3186886/spline-interpolation-why-cube-with-2nd-derivative)
as following [Cubic Spline Interpolation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LgodR7pwwW8) in youtube. The example in the youtube is below.

[image]

Implemented using [scipy.interpolate.splrep](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) and try to understand what the returns of the splrep function are.

> Given the set of data points (x[i], y[i]) determine a smooth spline approximation of degree k on the interval xb <= x <= xe.
>   **Returns**
>   tck : tuple
>   A tuple 
> (t,c,k) containing the vector of knots, the B-spline coefficients, and the degree of the spline.

```
import numpy as np
from pylab import plt, mpl

plt.style.use('seaborn')
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'serif'
%matplotlib inline

def create_plot(x, y, styles, labels, axlabels):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
    for i in range(len(x)):
        plt.plot(x[i], y[i], styles[i], label=labels[i])
        plt.xlabel(axlabels[0])
        plt.ylabel(axlabels[1])
    plt.legend(loc=0)

x = np.array([3.0, 4.5, 7.0, 9.0])
y = np.array([2.5, 1.0, 2.5, 0.5])
create_plot([x], [y], ['b'], ['y'], ['x', 'y'])
```

[image]

```
import scipy.interpolate as spi  
interpolation = spi.splrep(x, y, k=3)

IX = np.linspace(3, 9, 100)
IY = spi.splev(IX, interpolation)

create_plot(
    [x, IX], 
    [y, IY], 
    ['b', 'ro'],
    ['x', 'IY:interpolation'], 
    ['x', 'y']
)
```

[image]

### Questions

How to interpret and understand the return values and which resources to look into to understand?

> A tuple (t,c,k) containing the vector of knots, the B-spline coefficients, and the degree of the spline.

#### The return value on Knots

```
interpolation[0]
```

**array([3., 3., 3., 3., 9., 9., 9., 9.])**

I thought the first tuple element would be the knots which would be the **x**, but not. What are these 3., 3. ... values?

#### The return values on B-spline co-efficient

```
interpolation[1]
```

**array([ 2.5 , -2.21111111, 6.18888889, 0.5 , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ])**

Please help or suggest where I should look into and what to understand about "B-spline coefficient" to be able to interpret these values?

The solution of the first interval is (0.186566, 1.6667, 0.24689), hence I thought these values would be in the 2nd element, but not. How the solution values would relate to the return values?

[image]